# How to get to Medan (Sumatra island, Indonesia) from Singapore?

Tags: budget, singapore, itineraries, indonesia

I "heard" it was possible to go by plane or by ferry to [Medan (Sumatra island, Indonesia)](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Medan,+Medan+City,+North+Sumatra,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@2.7016627,101.5396721,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303131cc1c3eb2fd:0x23d431c8a6908262).

I want to find the different ways to go from Singapore to [Medan (Sumatra island, Indonesia)](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Medan,+Medan+City,+North+Sumatra,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@2.7016627,101.5396721,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303131cc1c3eb2fd:0x23d431c8a6908262) in order to choose the price/complexity ratio that suits me best.

Note: I am **not** planning to go to the [Aceh region](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Aceh,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@1.4952196,101.6147533,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x30399bdf507cc4bd:0x1039d80b220ca60) because of this: [What are the restrictions imposed by the Sharia law in Aceh, Sumatra?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48242/what-are-the-restrictions-imposed-by-the-sharia-law-in-aceh-sumatra)

Comment: There is no international ferry link going to Medan. You would have to transit by Batam (from Singapore) Dumai (from Melaka, Malaysia) or Tujung Balai (from Klang, Malaysia). If you want specific info about north Sumatra, ask me. I lived 2 years there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Options I found:

- Fly directly from Singapore to [Medan](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Medan,+Medan+City,+North+Sumatra,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@2.7016627,101.5396721,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303131cc1c3eb2fd:0x23d431c8a6908262) for circa **90 USD**.
- Bus from Singapore to [Johor Bahru Airport in Malaysia (called "Senai International Airport")](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Johor+Bahru,+Johor,+Malaysia/@1.5448725,103.6967269,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x31da12c6d36b3a27:0xd5f4b21db593d4f5) with [causewaylink](http://www.causewaylink.com.my/) for circa 3 USD, then direct flight to [Medan](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Medan,+Medan+City,+North+Sumatra,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@2.7016627,101.5396721,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303131cc1c3eb2fd:0x23d431c8a6908262) with Airasia for circa 40 USD. So a total of circa ** USD**. Note that [AirAsia has a partnership with causewaylink to provide this ticket for free](http://www.airasia.com/sg/en/latest-news/jhb-shuttle-bus.page). I took this bus in May 2015 & it took around 1h45 to do the bus journey at a low-peak time, allow at least 3h if travelling on a week end or public holiday.
- Fly to [Kuala Lumpur](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Kuala+Lumpur,+Federal+Territory+of+Kuala+Lumpur,+Malaysia/@3.4022451,102.1812402,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x31cc49c701efeae7:0xf4d98e5b2f1c287d) (Malaysia) for circa 30 USD, then fly to [Medan](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Medan,+Medan+City,+North+Sumatra,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@2.7016627,101.5396721,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303131cc1c3eb2fd:0x23d431c8a6908262) for circa 30 USD. Found those prices using [Momondo](http://www.momondo.com/). So a total of circa **60 USD**
- Take the ferry to [Batam island (Indonesia)](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Batam+City,+Riau+Islands,+Republic+of+Indonesia/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x31d9bce8c054ce05:0x3039d80b220cbb0?sa=X&ei=H1BjVcKaIYS6uAT-jID4Cw&ved=0CIMBEPIBMA4) for circa 22 USD (45 min ride), then take another ferry to [Dumai (Indonesia)](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Dumai,+Dumai+City,+Riau,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@1.6675758,101.411459,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x31d3af399bc9f7d9:0xfaf97dec9a757b44) with the [Dumai Express](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dumai-Express-Group/150528784996206) for circa 25 USD (this one is a long ride, 6 to 8h). As explained in [theworldonwheels.com](http://www.theworldonwheels.com/2014/11/getting-sumatra-indonesia-singapore-boat-easy-guide.html) "To buy the ticket from Dumai, you need to visit a ticket agent who will sort you out – there’s no need to go to the port to buy a ticket.", & there does seem to be only 1 (yes one!) ferry per day. So this means potentially having to stay in Batam overnight (who knows?). Then [take a bus for around 10h from Dumai to Medan](http://www.journeum.com/dst/Asia/Indonesia/Sumatra/Riau/Dumai/Getting%20there/) for circa 13 USD. So a total of circa **60 USD**

All in all, my research seem to always point to taking a plane rather than a ferry... unless you really have a special reason for avoiding planes (transporting loads of luggages, transporting a bike, fear of planes, or else).

Here is another good reason **not** to take the ferry in Indonesia [How safe are the ferries in Indonesia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37998/how-safe-are-the-ferries-in-indonesia)

Note: you must add circa **12 USD** to every flight with **AirAsia** if you have a checked baggage

Note regarding **trains** going from Singapore to Johor Bahru: There's no point in taking the train to JB, the new terminal is very inconvenient and services are infrequent and unreliable. Take a bus instead.

Final note: there is nothing "special" to do in Medan, so if you arrive before 4pm try to plan your journey to your final destination straight from Medan (typically using a tourist bus or a public bus), roads can be dangerous at night so many transports do not work when it's dark (after 7pm). The hotel/hostel hosting you can provide more info, it's a typical thing to do.

---

#### Resources:

- AirAsia route map: http://www.airasia.com/sg/en/where-we-fly/route-map.page
- http://www.momondo.com
- http://www.senaiairport.com/travellers.asp?menuid=100129&rootid=100015&splid=1&parentid=100129
- https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/singapore-to-sumatra-292c3939-bfe4-48d0-9ef7-257f831a1b66
- http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowTopic-g294231-i9609-k4576284-Getting_to_Sumatra_Medan_from_Singapore_Kuala_Lumpur-Sumatra.html
- http://www.theworldonwheels.com/2014/11/getting-sumatra-indonesia-singapore-boat-easy-guide.html
- http://www.journeum.com/dst/Asia/Indonesia/Sumatra/Riau/Dumai/Getting%20there/
- https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dumai-Express-Group/150528784996206
- http://wikitravel.org/en/Batam
- http://wikitravel.org/en/Bintan
- http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Singapore/Medan

Comment: If you take indirect route, there are other Ferry (Melaka->Dumai or Klang -> Tunjung Balai) but then, you need to make a tourist visa in some consulate beforehand. There is no visa on arrival in those harbor (there is in Batam harbor, but that's definitely not the direct route)