# How much is a visitor affected by Ramadan in Aceh (Indonesia) considering it has Sharia law?

Tags: legal, indonesia, islam, ramadan, aceh

The Aceh province, in Indonesia, applies the Sharia law all year round. It does impact a traveler's visit whether one likes it or not, as pointed out in [What are the restrictions imposed by the Sharia law in Aceh, Sumatra?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48242/what-are-the-restrictions-imposed-by-the-sharia-law-in-aceh-sumatra)

The Ramadan last for about one month every year, & this is a highly spiritual time for Muslims all around the world. There is already a question regarding the Indonesia as a whole & its impact on a visitor [How much is a traveler affected by Ramadan in Indonesia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42874/how-much-is-a-traveler-affected-by-ramadan-in-indonesia)

I suppose that the Aceh province does get even stricter than it already is the rest of year. If so, what does it mean for a visitor?

Answer (score 4):

During Ramadan, the most important change is the Islamic fasting. This prohibits eating and drinking between (approximately) sunrise and sunset.

However, some muslims are allowed to eat. This includes children, the sick, the old, and pregnant women.

I have no special experience with Indonesia, but typically (even with Sharia in place), you will be able to buy food (i.e. supermarkets) during the whole day, as usual. Many restaurants however will not be open during day time, though. Most likely hotels with many western customers will still serve food.

Also, it is often considered impolite to eat and drink openly in front of those who are fasting.

Comment: We are speaking about a region that implements Sharia law, not just "another Muslim region". I'll vote down your answer as it misses the experience in this region that I am looking for (rather than a generic answer).

Comment: @AdrienBe I have never implied this is just "another Muslim region". I'm experienced with Sharia regions, just not Indonesia per se.

Comment: oh my bad. I removed my vote down. I'll vote your answer up. I'd really like to have an answer from someone who went there though. As every destination has its specificities.